# Find the remainder when $11^{2013}$ is divided by $ 61$

Tags: contest-math

How do I find the remainder when $11^{2013}$ is divided by $61$?  Brute force?  Without a calculator?  How did people do that?

Comment: HINT: $11^2\equiv -1\bmod 61$

Comment: What is that mod symbol?

Comment: Can someone explain what mod is?

Comment: x mod n means the remainder found when dividing x by n. Edit: Though the comment below mine has a more formal definition.

Comment: Well,$a \equiv b\bmod p$ means that $a-b=kp$ for some integer k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

- $61$ is a prime.
- Use Fermat's Little Theorem, which says: $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \ ( \ \text{mod} \ p )$.

Comment: So I'm doing 11^2012 == 1 (mod 2012)?

Comment: There's no variable in it, isn't there nothing to solve for? The x doesn't exist?

Comment: It might help to know for this that Fermat's little theorem requires that $p$ is prime, and states that $a^{p - 1} \equiv 1 (\mod p)$ for all $a$, given that $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

**Pattern Observation :**

reminder of $11^0 / 61 $ = $1$

reminder of $11^1 / 61 $ = $11$

reminder of $11^2 / 61 $ = $-1$

reminder of $11^3 / 61 $ = $-10$

There after the reminder repeats as **1, 11, -1 ,-10** ,1, 11, -1 ,-10.... 
so remainders repeat with period $4$

as $2013$ when divided by $4$ gives reminder $1$  , it will have same remainder as reminder of $11^1 / 61 $ .
Hence answer is $11$

Comment: $2013\equiv 1\bmod 4$ so the answer should 11. This has nothing to do with $11$ as period is $4$.

Comment: @asatzhh .Thanks for the correction . Enthusiasm made me mad .

Answer (score 0):

Using what asatzhh notes it simply  is $11$; because $$11^{2013} \equiv 11*(11^2)^{1006} \equiv 11*(121)^{1006}\equiv 11*(61*2-1)^{1006}\equiv 11*(-1)^{1006} \equiv 11$$